# Write json to local disk javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I wrote a small application(proof of concept) in angular.js and i encountered the need of persisting simple data between application instantiations.

I would like to know if there's **a way of storing JSON objects to a local file**, on my computer, without server or database intervention.

The easiest solution I found is using ColdFusion, but this requires setting up a server too.

Thanks!

Comment: I use https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage, it saves data to your localstorage.

Comment: As @AtaurRahimChowdhury recommended. That is the perfect module out there.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. 
I haven't had the time to try ngStorage, but few weeks ago I used it in my project and I am very satisfied.
It stores data on the browser and **it is persistent from a session to another one** and that's a key point. 
But, for example, if you uninstall your browser all that data goes away. 

So, it is **dependent to the browser** not to your computer disk storage.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Local Storage.

you can store Json object like this:

```
var jsonObejct = {'city':'New Yourk', 'country':'USA'}

localStorage.setItem('jsonObejct',JSON.stringify(jsonObejct));
```

you can retrieve from Storage Like:

```
var loadedObj = localStorage.getItem('jsonObejct');
```

Comment: That's a low quality, link answer